# Mottie virtual keyboard and Chosen Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to get the following two excellent jQuery plugins to work together.

- virtual keyboard plugin by Mottie: (github.com/Mottie/Keyboard)
- a selector called Chosen which does filtering of the options as the user types:
  (harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) Here is an example of what I mean (when I use my physical keyboard): [chosen auto-filtering while typing with physical keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU58j.png)

Unfortunately this filtering does not happen when I use mottie's keyboard. Here is a screenshot of what happens:
[chosen auto-filtering while typing with mottie fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvEr2.png)

My mottie javascript is:

`$('input, textarea').keyboard({layout: 'qwerty', usePreview: false, autoAccept: true}).addTyping();`

Any idea why? Probably this question could be answered by the two developers (@mottie)

PS: Since need 10 points to post images I have them as links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the select2 open event to initialize the keyboard ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/egb3a1sk/230/))

```
var keys = {
    bksp: 8,
    tab: 9,
    enter: 13,
    space: 32,
    delete: 46
};

$('select')
    .select2({
        placeholder: "Select a state"
    })
    .on("select2:open", function (e) {
        $('.select2-container--open .select2-search__field').keyboard({
            // Used by jQuery UI position utility
            position: {
                // null = attach to input/textarea;
                // use $(sel) to attach elsewhere
                of: $(document),
                my: 'center bottom',
                at: 'center bottom',
                // used when "usePreview" is false
                at2: 'center bottom'
            },
            reposition: true,
            usePreview: false,
            change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
                var key = (keyboard.last.key || '').toLowerCase();
                // trigger a keydown for "special" keys
                e.type = keys[key] ? 'keydown' : 'input';
                e.which = keys[key] || key.charCodeAt(0);
                keyboard.$el.trigger(e);
            }
        })
        // activate the typing extension
        .addTyping({
            showTyping: true,
            delay: 50
        });
    });
```

Update: special key interaction added to allow pressing enter on the virtual keyboard

Include this css to remove the blue outline:

```
.ui-keyboard-input-current {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```